# Is it possible to have the materialize-products goal of tycho-p2-director-plugin include source features?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

I am using tycho-source-plugin and tycho-source-feature-plugin to generate plugin source jars and source features.

I am generating a p2 repository using tycho-p2-repository-plugin and a product using tycho-p2-director-plugin.

For the p2 repository, I was able to include source jars by adding a category.xml and appending ".source" to the id of all the features.

For the product, I can't find any documentation or examples for how to include source jars with the materialized product or the product archive.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled across this today during work.
Sorry for reviving this, but perhaps this helps someone.

The way it worked for me was to specify a source feature in my product file and let tycho generate sources and a source feature from an existing feature.

Product file:

```
<feature id="com.some.feature" installMode="root"/>
<feature id="com.some.feature.source" installMode="root"/>
```

In my "API" bundle that contributes source, I added this in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>doc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>plugin-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I created a feature project that references this bundle. In the pom.xml of this project I added:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-source-feature-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>doc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>source-feature</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attached-p2-metadata</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>p2-metadata</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Finally, in the project's parent POM I added:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attached-p2-metadata</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>p2-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The product editor itself contains an error marker, but that can be ignored.
Tycho itself builds the product and the source attachment is automatically set in the running Eclipse IDE.